# what does "preserved" mean here

Tags: meaning

> The Komodo dragon was the driving factor for an expedition to Komodo
>   Island by W. Douglas Burden in 1926. After returning with 12 **preserved**
>   specimens and 2 live ones, this expedition provided the inspiration
>   for the 1933 movie King Kong.

Does it means "died Komodo dragons"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (dead) specimens were pickled (probably in formaldehyde).

Similar to 1.4 here except it is not food, but a scientific sample:

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/preserve

The preservation processes differ, of course. But it means to "treat something chemically to prevent spoilage".

Comment: +1 I think the last sentence is intended to convey that it might not have specifically been formaldehyde, but any of many possible chemicals, or a non-chemical technique. Formaldehyde is just an example. (If not, I just said it.)

Comment: I'll add *probably* :-)